# Como forçar o typescript a interpretar um parâmetro como uma namespace ao invés de uma classe quando eles tem o mesmo nome - gRPC

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Eu estou implementando um pequeno crud usando gRPC e typescript, o meu problema é: Os stubs autogerdos criam uma classe e um "type" para cada parâmetro no `protofile`. Por exemplo, o parâmetro UserId gera uma classe com getUserId, etc, e uma namespace com o "type" UserId.

O problema é que quando eu tento usar o método no meu `client`, o typescript interpreta o parâmetro do método como a classe e nāo o tipo.

Então, ao invés de `getUsersById({id: 1}, callback)`... ele me pede algo como `getUsersById(new UserId)`.

### user.Proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package userServicePKG;

message User {
    int32 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
    int32 age = 3;
}

message UserId {
    int32 id = 1;
}

service UserService{
    rpc getUserById (UserId) returns (User);
}
```

### UserServiceClientPb.ts (Protobuf generated) - Definição da Função

```
methodInfogetUserById = new grpcWeb.AbstractClientBase.MethodInfo(
    User,
    (request: UserId) => {
      return request.serializeBinary();
    },
    User.deserializeBinary
  );

  getUserById(
    request: UserId,
    metadata: grpcWeb.Metadata | null): Promise<User>;

  getUserById(
    request: UserId,
    metadata: grpcWeb.Metadata | null,
    callback: (err: grpcWeb.Error,
               response: User) => void): grpcWeb.ClientReadableStream<User>;

  getUserById(
    request: UserId,
    metadata: grpcWeb.Metadata | null,
    callback?: (err: grpcWeb.Error,
               response: User) => void) {
    if (callback !== undefined) {
      return this.client_.rpcCall(
        new URL('/userServicePKG.UserService/getUserById', this.hostname_).toString(),
        request,
        metadata || {},
        this.methodInfogetUserById,
        callback);
    }
    return this.client_.unaryCall(
    this.hostname_ +
      '/userServicePKG.UserService/getUserById',
    request,
    metadata || {},
    this.methodInfogetUserById);
  }
```

### user_pb.d.ts (Protobuf Generated) - Define os tipos e Classes:

```
export class UserId extends jspb.Message {
  getId(): number;
  setId(value: number): UserId;

  serializeBinary(): Uint8Array;
  toObject(includeInstance?: boolean): UserId.AsObject;
  static toObject(includeInstance: boolean, msg: UserId): UserId.AsObject;
  static serializeBinaryToWriter(message: UserId, writer: jspb.BinaryWriter): void;
  static deserializeBinary(bytes: Uint8Array): UserId;
  static deserializeBinaryFromReader(message: UserId, reader: jspb.BinaryReader): UserId;
}

export namespace UserId {
  export type AsObject = {
    id: number,
  }
}
```

### Client.Vue:

```
const client = new UserServiceClient('http://localhost:5001', null, null);

let userId = { id:1 };
client.getUserById(userId, function (error: grpcWeb.Error, response: any) {
     //do something
});
```

O parâmetro userId causa o seguinte erro:

> Argument of type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserId'.
> Type '{ id: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'UserId': getId, setId, serializeBinary, toObject, and 8 more.Vetur(2345)

Me parece que o typescript deduz que o primeiro parâmetro `getUserById` é do tipo `Class UserId` e não do tipo que vem da **namespace** `UserId`.

Tem algo que eu possa fazer sobre isso? Ja que foi código autogerado pelo **grpc_web**, ele deveria interpretar corretamente né? Ah não ser que seja um erro meu na implementação do gRPC ou mal uso do typescript.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Agradeço se indicarem problemas com a pergunta também, obrigado.

Comment: A resposta está na mensagem de erro. Quando faz isso `let userId = { id:1 };
client.getUserById(userId, function (error: grpcWeb.Error, response: any) {
     //do something
});` essa variável `userId` não é instancia de `UserId ` e por isso não pode ser passado como parâmetro para essa função. Crie uma instancia da classe, como leitor não posso fazer isso pois a pergunta não fornece informações suficientes para instanciar a classe `UserId` não mostra o constructor e eu conheço 5 libs que possuem o tipo `jspb.Message`, que `UserId` deriva e todos diferentes, impossibilitando uma resposta.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Muito obrigado pela ajuda, `jspb.Message` vem do seguinte import `import * as jspb from "google-protobuf"`, será que ajuda em algo?

Comment: No manual diz para instanciar e  [não subclassear](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#message) `jspb.Message`. Vai ter que modificar a função.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa tipar corretamente sua variável userId. Quando você faz {} para instanciar um objeto, ele vai ser do tipo Object. Faça:

```
let userId: UserId = new UserId().setId(1); // Tipado como UserId

client.getUserById(userId, function (error: grpcWeb.Error, response: any) {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: você está certo, eu tinha encontrado a resposta mas acabei não tendo tempo de responder aqui. Inclusive esse link aqui me ajudou bastante https://grpc.io/docs/platforms/web/basics/ . O grande problema é que a maioria dos tutoriais online explicam clients grpc em outras tecnologias e não o gRPC web, porque ainda é muito novo. Muito obrigado pela resposta.